# DTM - multiple values to single eVar in single call

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I have a set of eVars defined in DTM(dynamic tag manager). I would be setting those values in a custom event in my code. There will be multiple instances where I would be setting this values. I can trigger multiple s.tl() calls and set those values. But I want to reduce the number of s.tl() calls. Is there any way to make one s.tl() call and set multiple values to the same eVars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your options for sending multiple values to the same variable on the same hit are:**

---

**[Use a `list` variable](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/listN.html)**

Since you wanted to use an `eVar`, the closest to what you want to do is probably a `list` variable. It is mostly like an `eVar`, but not as flexible. Also, you only get 3 of them per report suite, so you should try to see if the other options will work for you first, unless this is a super important KPI and the other options just won't work for you (from a reporting PoV).

**Example:**

`s.list1='foo1,foo2,foo3';`

---

**[Use a merchandising `eVar` (product syntax)](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/var_merchandising_impl.html)**

This method uses a regular `eVar` but you configure it as a product syntax merchandising `eVar` (configuration done within the Adobe Analytics Admin interface).

**Example:**

`s.products=";;;;;eVar1=foo1,;;;;;eVar1=foo2,;;;;;eVar1=foo3";`

***Note:*** You may optionally want to specify a category and/or product depending on what you are ultimately trying to do (especially if your site has ecommerce tracking; it helps filter this out of actual products)

---

**[Use a list `prop`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/list_props.html)**

You can configure any (or all!) of the 75 available props in the interface to be a list prop.  The main downsides to a list prop is the 100 char limit for the prop (which may be too short, given you have multiple values), and that it is a traffic variable (only hit scope).  But.. depending on what you are actually trying to record and report on, a list `prop` may be all you need.

**Example:**

```
s.prop1='foo1,foo2,foo3';
```